# How would one change the spell-checking style while preserving highlight color?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, spell-checking

Currently when working with vim's spellcheck a word is highlighted a certain color based on the type of error it is. Instead of highlighting the erroneous word I'd like it to be underlined with the highlighted color. I'm aware it's possible underline a certain highlight group with `cterm=underline`, and I can change to foreground color with the `ctermfg` option, but that changes the color of the word *and* underline whereas I just want the underline to be a different color.

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible. It looks like one can define the color attribute only for `undercurl` and `strikethrough` using the `guisp` attribute, and that is only possible in the gui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Vim 8.2.0863 (May 2020) this can be done with `ctermul` if your terminal supports it:

```
:hi SpellBad cterm=underline ctermul=blue
```

Also see [the PR](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/6011); this should be supported on VTE-based terminals, KiTTY, and perhaps some more. You can check if `underline_rgb` is present in `terminalprops()` (which was added a few patchlevels later, in 8.2.0970). Don't forget to set the correct `TERM` value, otherwise it won't work (e.g. `xterm-kitty`).

If you're using an older version or a terminal that doesn't support this then you're out of luck. Vim doesn't directly "draw" anything, it just sends text interspersed with escape codes for colouring, positioning, etc. and it's up to the terminal to interpret that.

Neovim doesn't support this at the time of writing; you can [search the Neovim repo](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/search?q=ctermul) to see if it's supported if you're reading this a few years after posted.

---

In gvim you can do this with `guisp`, which is used for both strikethrough and undercurl (but not underline):

```
:hi SpellBad gui=underline guisp=blue
```

This value is also used in the terminal if you enable `termguicolors` and the terminal supports `ctermul`.

Comment: I've updated my vim config file and everything seems to work as expected, including mixing foreground and underline colors (eg red underline and blue fg) thanks for the update! Just a note to those using neovim, as of 0.4.4 `ctermul=<color>` doesn't work.